# JQuery call input value from another function async

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, ion-range-slider

Using ion rangeslider for this. I am trying to call the value of my prettify function which I have set to log scaling. My log scaling works but when I try to call it back into my other async functions I am unable to get the same result.

I want the result I get from the prettify function to go through the onStart, OnChange, onFinish functions.

```
onStart: function(data) {
    imprValue = data.from;
  console.log("onstart:" + imprValue);
    inputValues();
 },
 onChange: function(data) {
    imprValue = data.from;
   console.log("onchange:" + imprValue);
    inputValues();
 },
 onFinish: function(data) {
   imprValue = prettify();
   console.log("onfinish:" + imprValue);
   inputValues();
 },
 prettify: function(n) {
  // current position
  var position = Math.floor(n / this.max * 100);
  // position will be between 0 and 100
  var minPos = 0,
      maxPos = 100;
  // calculate logarithms
  var minLog = Math.log(this.min),
      maxLog = Math.log(this.max);
  // calculate adjustment factor
  var scale = (maxLog-minLog) / (maxPos-minPos);
  // round numbers
  n = Math.floor(Math.exp(minLog + scale * (position - minPos)));
  console.log("prettify function:" + n);
  return n;
 }
```

Jsfidde here:
http://jsfiddle.net/jsbegin/7dbowqfd/61/

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking. You're not calling `prettify` in `onStart` or `onChange`. Why not?

Comment: I was just testing one at a time to start. I found the answer myself and posted it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working, wanted to post it in case anyone else ever is looking.

You need to call it like so:

```
imprValue = this.prettify(data.from);
```

Working jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jsbegin/7dbowqfd/68/

Answer (score 1):

You should know, that build-in prettify function was made only to visually improve sliders values. It does not affect original data.

If you want to transform original data too, you should create external function. Like this:

```
var $range = $(".js-range-slider");
var $result = $(".js-result");

function transform(num) {
    var n = num.toString();
    return n.replace(/(\d{1,3}(?=(?:\d\d\d)+(?!\d)))/g, "$1" + ",");
}

$range.ionRangeSlider({
    type: "single",
    grid: true,
    min: 10000,
    max: 10000000,
    from: 10000,
    prettify_separator: ",",
    onStart: function(data) {
        $result.text(transform(data.from));
    },
    onChange: function(data) {
        $result.text(transform(data.from));
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/133bvhn3/

Comment: Thank you Denis, and thanks for the awesome Ion rangeslider